# C dynamic allocate chunk of memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, linked-list

Here is my data structure

```
struct Node{
      int x;
      Node *next;
      Node *prev;
}
```

If I allocate memory

```
Node *A = malloc (sizeof (Node) * 10);
```

How can I access each box in the array using array index in this case? or it's not possible?

My goal just want to make a linked list in this chunk of memory.

basically i want to assign a block of memory and then assign their prev and next....

maybe it's confusing , sorry about my wording..

Comment: Are you trying to write C, or C++?

Comment: It is probably C; otherwise, the `malloc` would fail since he needs to typecast it.

Comment: if it's c then must have to write struct Node *A instead of Node *A...Otherwise compiler will give error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you an array of 10 `Node`s, accessible through `A`. Now, all you have to do is e.g.

```
A[0].next = &A[1];
```

to set the `next` value of the first node.

Comment: You have an *array* of `Node`s, but they could be linked in any order (e.g. `A[0].next = &A[7]`). It's a little unusual, but it's not crazy.

Comment: by the way, what is the initial value in A[i].x ?

Comment: Unspecified. You should initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` returned `void*` then you should cast it for your type `Node*`

`Node *A = (Node *)malloc (sizeof (Node) * 10);`

Comment: If it's C++, the cast is mandatory (but `new Node[10]` would be better). If it's C, the cast is not required, and stylistically should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Allocating many nodes the way you do may efficient for memory management but I wouldn't access them like an array. I think you should rely on the linked list and not mix the the two methods since it would easily lead to bugs hard to trace and evn harder to fix.